# WPF event mystery

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new in WPF and I am unable to understand this behavior of my code... I have a class of user control...

```
public class CustomControl1 : Control
{
    .... some code here ... 

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public CustomControl1()
    {
        // user items
        UserItems = new ObservableCollection<Label>();
        UserItems.CollectionChanged += UserItems_CollectionChanged;            
    }

    // informace o pridani do kolekce
    void UserItems_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // !! ?? WHY IS THIS EVENT FIRED AFTER XAML SETS UserItems PROPERTY TO NEW INSTANCE ??  
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// User items
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<Label> UserItems
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Label>)GetValue(UserItemsProperty); }
        set 
        {
            // XAML code sets this value with new instance of ObservableCollection !
            SetValue(UserItemsProperty, value);
        }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for UserItems.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UserItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("UserItems", typeof(ObservableCollection<Label>), typeof(CustomControl1), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

}
```

I use this custom control in XAML window...

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary1;assembly=WpfCustomControlLibrary1" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <c:CustomControl1>
            <c:CustomControl1.UserItems>
                <Label>Menu1</Label>
                <Label>Menu2</Label>
            </c:CustomControl1.UserItems>
        </c:CustomControl1>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I debug this code,

1) Constructor creates new instance of ObservableCollection and registers *UserItems_CollectionChanged*. **to this instance**.

2) UserItems property setter is raised and UserItems is set to a **NEW INSTANCE** of ObservableCollection. This instance **should not have *UserItems_CollectionChanged* registered to it**.

3) Event **UserItems_CollectionChanged** is fired for Menu1 and Menu2 labels. **WHY?** new instance of ObservableCollection should not raise this events !

There is something in this code or behind WPF what I do not understand. Can you help me ? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Check the sender parameter of `UserItems_CollectionChanged` to find whether it is the new instance or old instance which raises the event.

Comment: Checked using ObjectIDGenerator... New instance of collection raised this event.

Comment: Are you sure new ObservableCollection is created and overwritten in  `UserItems` property? It could be that you just got only one instance?

Comment: You are true. My mystake. XAML does not create new instance of ObservableCollection. It only adds new items to it. Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

UserItems in xaml produces a "new view" side collection and it pushes over the existing one. The problem might be related to the approach taken. You could have an event for the setter of collection and fire it when the UI produces new instance and invokes setter. Subscribe to it and then hook up your collection changed handler.